# Поиск значений заданного столбца по всем таблицам БД

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Создал БД с двумя таблицами и решил создать цикл для поиска значения столбца во всех таблицах.

Создал цикл:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  c_ColName varchar2(80) := 'login_name';
  c_Val varchar2(80) := 'nicolia';
  v_SQL varchar2(3000);

  CURSOR C1
  IS
  SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tab_columns
  WHERE column_name = c_ColName;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
  FOR R1 IN C1 loop
     v_SQL := R1.table_name;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_SQL));
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL USING c_Val, c_Val;
  END loop;
END;
```

Но при запуске выводится только сообщение об успешном завершении и ничего больше, т.е. цикл не возвращает имени таблицы в которой содержится искомый столбец:

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Сами таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
    login_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    login_name char(80)
);

CREATE TABLE pass
(
    pass_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    pass_password char(80),
    pass_login_id INT
);

ALTER TABLE pass ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (pass_login_id) REFERENCES login(login_id);

CREATE SEQUENCE login_auto_incr START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE pass_auto_incr START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

INSERT INTO login VALUES (login_auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 'nicolia');
INSERT INTO login VALUES (login_auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 'niclas');

INSERT INTO pass VALUES (pass_auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 'fkxhj4', 1);
INSERT INTO pass VALUES (pass_auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 'ndh3', 2);
```

Comment: Выполните запрос, который в курсоре отдельно и посмотрите результат. Думаю он ничего не возвращает, так как у вас нет таблиц где было бы имя колонки login_name маленькими буквами. `select * from user_tab_columns` сразу покажет, что по умолчанию все имена в Oracle большими буквами

Comment: после того как вы поменяете имя колонки при поиске на большие буквы, вы столкнетесь с проблемой на execute immediate, так как имя таблицы не является SQL запросом. вам надо составить текст запроса, включив в него имя таблицы

Comment: А после того как напишите корректный SQL запрос для execute immediate вы обнаружите следующую проблему - скорее всего возникнет ошибка, так как вы не указали куда execute immediate должен вернуть результат. Если хоть какая то выборка может быть получена из выполняемого динамически запроса, вы должны явно указать что с этой выборкой делать (например указав bulk collect into). Так же обратите внимание, что блок PL/SQL в принципе не может вернуть набор строк (если вы не используете pipe row или возврат курсора)

Comment: cоставить текст запроса, включив в него имя таблицы - этот блок кода нужно разместить в BEGIN ... END заменив FOR R1 IN C1?

Comment: нет, просто в текстовой переменной `'select ... from ' || R1.table_name || ' ...'` или какой запрос вы хотели выполнить с помощью execute

Answer (score 2):

Участник [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) пояснил в коментариях [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821410/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85#comment1307364_821410), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821410/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85#comment1307370_821410), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821410/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85#comment1307392_821410), что не так в коде вопроса.
Не буду повторяться, просто покажу наглядно, что он имел ввиду.
Поиск всех значений заданой колонки во всех таблицах стандартной схемы примеров HR:

```sql
set serveroutput on autoprint on
var rc refcursor
declare
  colName varchar2 (80) := 'job_id';
  sqlStmt varchar2 (32767);
begin
    for r in (
        select table_name
        from all_tab_columns
        where column_name = upper (colName)
        and owner = 'HR') loop
        sqlStmt := sqlStmt||
            'select '''||r.table_name||''' "table", '||colName||', count(*) cnt '||
            'from HR.'||r.table_name||' '||
            'group by '||colName||' union all'||chr (10);
    end loop;
    sqlStmt := regexp_replace (sqlStmt, ' union all$');
    open :rc for coalesce (sqlStmt,q'[select 'No tables found' warn from dual]');
end;
/
```

Результат (только часть записей для наглядности):

```
table            JOB_ID            CNT
---------------- ---------- ----------
JOBS             AC_ACCOUNT          1
EMPLOYEES        ST_MAN              5
JOB_HISTORY      AC_ACCOUNT          2
EMP_DETAILS_VIEW IT_PROG             5

65 rows selected.
```